# Python 2.7: How to determine maxtasksperchild in multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, memory, pandas, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a python program with which I would like to munge 10 large CSV's. Each CSV is 1 column x 5 million rows.

Inside this program is a function called make_pickle() which accepts a file path, loads the file, and then save the pickle. It looks something like:

```
def make_pickle(path):
    df1 = pandas.read_csv(path)
    df2 = <do stuff to df1>
    df3 = <do stuff to df2>

    df3.to_pickle(<modified path>)

    del df1
    del df2
    del df3
    gc.collect()
```

and I call it like this:

```
import gc
import pandas
import multiprocessing




def make_pickle(path):
    df1 = pandas.read_csv(path)
    df2 = <do stuff to df1>
    df3 = <do stuff to df2>

    df3.to_pickle(<modified path>)

    del df1
    del df2
    del df3
    gc.collect()





paths_to_process = [<path1>, 
                    <path2>, 
                    <path3>, 
                    <path4>, 
                    <path5>, 
                    <path6>, 
                    <path7>,
                    <path8>,
                    <path9>] 




if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()       # This is necessary for Windows
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)         # multiprocessing.cpu_count() is 4, so I'll use 3

    pool.map(make_pickle, paths_to_process)
```

I let this code run for a while and I and up with MemoryError for some reason. 
I have tried adding

```
del df1
del df2
del df3
```

in

```
make_pickle()
```

but that didn't really help.

I tried to find some documentation on

```
multiprocessing.Pool(maxtasksperchild =??)
```

but I couldn't find anything that would suggest a number to set it to.

What do I do?

Comment: `maxtasksperchild` probably won't help here - that's used if you think your child processes are leaking resources, and want to restart them to release those resources back to the OS. In your case, each child is probably only running 2-4 tasks (since you have 3 processes and 10 items), so there probably isn't much time for a leak to build up. You can set `maxtasksperchild` to 1 to confirm that. The more likely problem is that loading  multiple csv's into memory simultaneously across your processes is exhausting your memory. Try using only 2 processes in the pool, to reduce the memory load.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't load the csv's into memory, just their paths. Can you comment on how setting `maxtaskperchild` to 1 would help me?

Comment: Setting `maxtaskperchild` to 1 would restart each process in your pool after it processed a single task, which is the most aggressive setting you could use to free any leaked resources. My suspicion is that *won't* help you, though, since I don't think a memory leak is the problem. You say you're not loading the csv's into memory, but you're calling `read_csv` on each path and then doing some operations on the data frame, right? That requires loading the contents of the file in memory, though ideally without ever having the whole file in memory. Maybe it's using more memory than you think?

Comment: Does ``maxtaskperchild=1`` reduce the performance, increase the runtime cince in requires restart each process after finishing one process?